# NodeMCU successfully uploaded sketch but it does not work from Arduino IDE

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, ide, iot

NodeMCU successfully compiled and uploaded a simple blink sketch on board, no errors at all, but the LED stays on constantly and does not blink. Also I have checked the power is enough. I have checked this with all pins but the red LED only stays on and doesn't blink. I have no idea what could have gone wrong. And how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it....
turns out that in the tools, the board was selected to be NodeMCU 0.9
when it should actually have been NodeMCU 1.0
so i just changed it to NodeMCU 1.0 and it worked!

Comment: accept your answer to finalize this Q&A

Comment: @Juraj isn't there a 24h waiting period as on other sites?